# Got ValueError, when the value is in the list

Tags: python, valueerror

Initially, my task was to create a function, that will find last index of the longest word in a string, assuming that string can be very long. One more limit: function should not do any copies of words.

```
def find(x: str) -> int:
    len = 0
    res = []
    flag = False
    strip = ' \n\r\v\t\f'
    for el in x:
        if el in strip:
            if flag:
                if len:
                    res.append(len)
                    len = 0
                flag = False
            pass
        else:
            if not flag:
                flag = True
                len += 1
            else:
                len += 1
    if flag:
        res.append(len)

    print(res, max(res), max(res) in res, sep='\n' )  #this is for testing

    return res.index(max(res), -1)
```

All should be OK, but ValueError happens, when I'm trying to print this:

```
print(find(' a b 21231 21 21 1 22122 12c'))
-------------
[1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3]
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/*****/Documents/Навчання/Прога/22/32b.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(find(' a b 21231 21 21 1 22122 12c'))
  File "C:/Users/*****/Documents/Навчання/Прога/22/32b.py", line 23, in find
    return res.index(max(res), -1)
True
ValueError: 5 is not in list

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure that this was caused by garbage collector.

But sometimes it works:

```
print(find(' 123 123 sad'))
-------------
[3, 3, 3]
3
True
2
```

I could go in another way with reversed lists, but first one bothers me a lot.

P.S. Attached the full error message

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message. Also, `len` is a name of a built-in function, do not redefine it.

Comment: Well, you explicitly tell `index` to just look at the very last element.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED -
Get rid of the optional argument from `index` method from the `return` statement and use the `index` method on the reversed list then convert the index relative to the original list:

```
return res.index(max(res), -1)
```

to

```
l.reverse()
return len(l) - 1 - l.index('l')
```